# Webpack + Azure-Storage + Node.js

Tags: node.js, webpack, azure-storage

I'm trying to read an azure-storage file using node.js and bundling with webpack. However, I can't seem to get the core node.js modules to be bundled with webpack. Though everything compile without any issue, I however get run time errors. See attached runtime errors: 
     [Chrome Runtime Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVuHa.png)

Can someone assist. Here's my webpack file:

```
 const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: path.relative(process.cwd(), path.join(__dirname, ".", "css", "style.css")),
});

module.exports = env => {
    const plugins = [extractSass];
    if (env && env.substring(0, 4) === "prod") {
        plugins.push(
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                compress: {
                    warnings: false,
                },
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                },
            }),
        );
    }
    return {
        entry: __dirname + '/src/sdlTab.tsx',
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            libraryTarget: "amd"
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                    loader: "ts-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /\.exec\.js$/,
                    use: ['script-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: extractSass.extract({
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: "css-loader",
                                options: { importLoaders: 1 },
                            },
                            {
                                loader: "sass-loader",
                            },
                            {
                                loader: "postcss-loader",
                            },
                        ],
                        fallback: "style-loader",
                    }),
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
                }
            ]
        },
        target: "node",
        externals: [
            {
                react: true,
                "react-dom": true
            },
            // Ignore TFS/*, VSS/*, Favorites/* since they are coming from VSTS host
            /^TFS\//,
            /^VSS\//
        ],
        plugins: plugins

    };
};
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As discussed internally we resolved this question, for others may have the same issue, here is the answer:

Use the new Azure Storage V10 SDK npm package (@azure/storage-blob), instead of legacy SDK npm package (azure-storage). This is because, V10 SDK npm package supports both browser and Node.js runtime, while legacy doesn't.

```
npm install @azure/storage-blob
```

At the same time, make sure webpack config target is "web" instead of "node".

Here is a sample:

1. npm install @azure/storage-blob
2. Update accountName, accountSAS and containerName in the code; (make sure the storage account enables CORS settings in order to access from browsers)
3. run “webpack-cli index.js” directly to bundle. This will genearte “main.js” under “dist” folder by default
4. Put “index.html” under “dist” folder with generated “main.js”
5. Open “html.js” with browsers

Following are content of "index.js".

`import {
      StorageURL,
      AnonymousCredential,
      Aborter,
      BlockBlobURL
    } from "@azure/storage-blob";`

```
async function blobToString(blob) {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fileReader.onloadend = ev => {
      resolve(ev.target.result);
    };
    fileReader.onerror = reject;
    fileReader.readAsText(blob);
  });
}

async function main() {
  const accountName = "<account>"; // Storage account name
  const accountSAS = "<sas>"; // Storage account SAS token, starting with ?
  const conatinerName = "mycontainer"; // An existing container
  const blobName = `blob${new Date().getTime()}`;

  const pipeline = StorageURL.newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential());
  const blockBlobURL = new BlockBlobURL(
    `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${conatinerName}/${blobName}${accountSAS}`,
    pipeline
  );

  const content = "Hello World! This is the blockblob content";
  await blockBlobURL.upload(Aborter.none, content, content.length);

  const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobURL.download(
    Aborter.none,
    0
  );
  const blob = await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody;
  const text = await blobToString(blob);

  alert(text);
}

main()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Executed successfully!");
  })
  .catch(alert);
```